# LaTeX pentimal system symbols

Tags: pdftex, pgfmath

Not sure how to word the title of this question.

Basically, I'm attempting to create a package that will allow the use of the pentimal system in documents.

The project can be viewed [on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/bqzcqdwwsffk).

I have it working for numbers up to 20, but after that it gets a bit more complex.

I have some pseudo code for what I'm trying to do, but just cannot figure out how to do it in latex:

```
\newcommand{\pent}[1]
{
    % Draw numbers 1-20 (working)
}
\newcommand{\pentimal}[1]
{
    \ifthenelse{#1<21}
    {
        \pent{#1}
    }
    {
        \while(#1>20)
        {
            \pent{20}
            #1 -= 20
        }
        \pent{#1}
    }
}
```

So far I've got this:

```
\newcommand{\pentimal}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{#1<21}%
    {\pent{#1}}%
    {%
        \pgfmathparse{#1 + 0}%
        \whiledo{\pgfmathresult{}>20}%
        {%
            \pent{20}%
            \pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult{} - 20}%
        }%
        \pent{\pgfmathresult{}}%
    }%
}
```

but I keep getting errors that are not helpful in the slightest (such as `! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.` despite not using `\ifnum`).

Comment: I would recommend expl3 for this project.

Comment: #1 is not a macro. \pgfmathresult does not have arguments.  Also, you should use \pgfmathparse* to access previous values of \pgfmathresult.  To be safe, use \pgfmathsetmacro with different names.

Comment: Here is an [example](https://www.alanshawn.com/tech/2020/10/04/latex3-tutorial.html#arabic-numerals-to-english-0-99) of converting Arabic numerals to English with LaTeX3. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `expl3` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed for LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \legend_pentimal_digit:n
 {
  \int_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {1}{a}
    {2}{b}
    {3}{c}
    {4}{d}
    {5}{e}
    {6}{f}
    {7}{g}
    {8}{h}
    {9}{i}
    {10}{j}
    {11}{k}
    {12}{l}
    {13}{m}
    {14}{n}
    {15}{o}
    {16}{p}
    {17}{q}
    {18}{r}
    {19}{s}
    {20}{t}
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \legend_pentimal:n
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { 0 < #1 <= 20 }
   {
    \legend_pentimal_digit:n { #1 }
   }
   {
    \legend_pentimal_digit:n { 20 }
    \legend_pentimal:e { \int_eval:n { #1 - 20 } }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \legend_pentimal:n { e }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\pent}{m}
 {
  \legend_pentimal:n { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\pent{1}
\pent{2}
\pent{3}
\pent{4}
\pent{5}
\pent{6}
\pent{7}
\pent{8}
\pent{9}
\pent{10}
\pent{11}
\pent{12}
\pent{13}
\pent{14}
\pent{15}
\pent{16}
\pent{17}
\pent{18}
\pent{19}
\pent{20}

\pent{345}

\end{document}
```

Instead of the letters in the definition of `\legend_pentimal_digit:n`, you'll use your code for the numbers. Remember to use

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\pentimelOne}{}{<code>}
```

for the number one and so on.

The code just repeats the digit for 20 ahead of the last remainder, as you seem to be doing in your code. The function, in the case of a number greater than 20 prints the digit 20 and then calls itself on the number 20 less.

[image]

Taking the code from your project:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed for LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\pent}{m}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt,yscale=-0.25,xscale=0.25]
        \tikzset{line width=2pt}
        
        \ifthenelse{#1<11}{\clip rectangle (10pt, 25pt);}{\clip rectangle (20pt, 25pt);}
        
        % Vertical line
        \draw  (10,0) -- (10,25) ;
        
        % Left line 1
        \ifthenelse{\(#1<10\) \AND \(\NOT #1=5\)}{\draw   (0,0) -- (10,0) ;}{}
        
        % Left line 2
        \ifthenelse{\(#1>1 \AND #1<5\) \OR \(#1>6 \AND #1<10\)}{\draw   (0,5) -- (10,5) ;}{}
        
        % Left line 3
        \ifthenelse{\(#1>2 \AND #1<5\) \OR \(#1>7 \AND #1<10\)}{\draw   (0,10) -- (10,10) ;}{}
        
        % Left line 4
        \ifthenelse{#1=4 \OR #1=9}{\draw   (0,15) -- (10,15) ;}{}
        
        % Right line 1
        \ifthenelse{\(#1>10\) \AND \(\NOT #1=15\) \AND \(#1<20\)}{\draw   (10,0) -- (20,0) ;}{}
        
        % Right line 2
        \ifthenelse{\(#1>11 \AND #1<15\) \OR \(#1>16 \AND #1<20\)}{\draw   (10,5) -- (20,5) ;}{}
        
        % Right line 3
        \ifthenelse{\(#1>12 \AND #1<15\) \OR \(#1>17 \AND #1<20\)}{\draw   (10,10) -- (20,10) ;}{}
        
        % Right line 4
        \ifthenelse{#1=14 \OR #1=19}{\draw   (10,15) -- (20,15) ;}{}
        
        % Bottom-left loop
        \ifthenelse{#1>4}{\draw   (10,25) .. controls (9.66,25.02) and (9.31,25.03) .. (8.95,25.03) .. controls (4.85,25.03) and (1.53,23.72) .. (1.53,22.11) .. controls (1.53,20.5) and (4.85,19.2) .. (8.95,19.2) .. controls (9.31,19.2) and (9.66,19.21) .. (10,19.23) -- cycle ;}{}
        
        % Top-left loop
        \ifthenelse{#1>9}{\draw   (10,5.77) .. controls (9.66,5.79) and (9.31,5.8) .. (8.95,5.8) .. controls (4.85,5.8) and (1.53,4.5) .. (1.53,2.89) .. controls (1.53,1.28) and (4.85,-0.03) .. (8.95,-0.03) .. controls (9.31,-0.03) and (9.66,-0.02) .. (10,0) -- cycle ;}{}
        
        % Bottom-right loop
        \ifthenelse{#1>14}{\draw   (10,19.23) .. controls (10.34,19.21) and (10.69,19.2) .. (11.05,19.2) .. controls (15.15,19.2) and (18.47,20.5) .. (18.47,22.11) .. controls (18.47,23.72) and (15.15,25.03) .. (11.05,25.03) .. controls (10.69,25.03) and (10.34,25.02) .. (10,25) -- cycle ;}{}
        
        % Top-right loop
        \ifthenelse{#1>19}{\draw   (10,0) .. controls (10.34,-0.02) and (10.69,-0.03) .. (11.05,-0.03) .. controls (15.15,-0.03) and (18.47,1.28) .. (18.47,2.89) .. controls (18.47,4.5) and (15.15,5.8) .. (11.05,5.8) .. controls (10.69,5.8) and (10.34,5.79) .. (10,5.77) -- cycle ;}{}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \legend_pentimal_digit:n
 {
  \pent{ #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \legend_pentimal:n
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { 0 < #1 <= 20 }
   {
    \legend_pentimal_digit:n { #1 }
   }
   {
    \legend_pentimal_digit:n { 20 }
    \legend_pentimal:e { \int_eval:n { #1 - 20 } }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \legend_pentimal:n { e }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\pentimal}{m}
 {
  \legend_pentimal:n { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\rom}[1]{\romannumeral#1\relax}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline
        \textbf{Arabic} & \textbf{Pentimal} & \textbf{Roman} \\\hline
        
        1  & \pentimal{1}  & \rom{1}  \\\hline
        2  & \pentimal{2}  & \rom{2}  \\\hline
        3  & \pentimal{3}  & \rom{3}  \\\hline
        4  & \pentimal{4}  & \rom{4}  \\\hline
        5  & \pentimal{5}  & \rom{5}  \\\hline
        6  & \pentimal{6}  & \rom{6}  \\\hline
        7  & \pentimal{7}  & \rom{7}  \\\hline
        8  & \pentimal{8}  & \rom{8}  \\\hline
        9  & \pentimal{9}  & \rom{9}  \\\hline
        10 & \pentimal{10} & \rom{10} \\\hline
        11 & \pentimal{11} & \rom{11} \\\hline
        12 & \pentimal{12} & \rom{12} \\\hline
        13 & \pentimal{13} & \rom{13} \\\hline
        14 & \pentimal{14} & \rom{14} \\\hline
        15 & \pentimal{15} & \rom{15} \\\hline
        16 & \pentimal{16} & \rom{16} \\\hline
        17 & \pentimal{17} & \rom{17} \\\hline
        18 & \pentimal{18} & \rom{18} \\\hline
        19 & \pentimal{19} & \rom{19} \\\hline
        20 & \pentimal{20} & \rom{20} \\\hline
        21 & \pentimal{21} & \rom{21} \\\hline
        22 & \pentimal{22} & \rom{22} \\\hline
        23 & \pentimal{23} & \rom{23} \\\hline
        24 & \pentimal{24} & \rom{24} \\\hline
        25 & \pentimal{25} & \rom{25} \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline
        \textbf{Arabic} & \textbf{Pentimal} & \textbf{Roman} \\\hline
        
        26 & \pentimal{26} & \rom{26} \\\hline
        27 & \pentimal{27} & \rom{27} \\\hline
        28 & \pentimal{28} & \rom{28} \\\hline
        29 & \pentimal{29} & \rom{29} \\\hline
        30 & \pentimal{30} & \rom{30} \\\hline
        31 & \pentimal{31} & \rom{31} \\\hline
        32 & \pentimal{32} & \rom{32} \\\hline
        33 & \pentimal{33} & \rom{33} \\\hline
        34 & \pentimal{34} & \rom{34} \\\hline
        35 & \pentimal{35} & \rom{35} \\\hline
        36 & \pentimal{36} & \rom{36} \\\hline
        37 & \pentimal{37} & \rom{37} \\\hline
        38 & \pentimal{38} & \rom{38} \\\hline
        39 & \pentimal{39} & \rom{39} \\\hline
        40 & \pentimal{40} & \rom{40} \\\hline
        41 & \pentimal{41} & \rom{41} \\\hline
        42 & \pentimal{42} & \rom{42} \\\hline
        43 & \pentimal{43} & \rom{43} \\\hline
        44 & \pentimal{44} & \rom{44} \\\hline
        45 & \pentimal{45} & \rom{45} \\\hline
        46 & \pentimal{46} & \rom{46} \\\hline
        47 & \pentimal{47} & \rom{47} \\\hline
        48 & \pentimal{48} & \rom{48} \\\hline
        49 & \pentimal{49} & \rom{49} \\\hline
        50 & \pentimal{50} & \rom{50} \\\hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't know that was a thing, thanks for the help :)